# NullPointer exception in Jsoup Element

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I want to show newspapers headline and news in android application. So at first I create a Java project and did my task perfectly. here is my java projects classes

Main.java

```
package com.emon.newsportal;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        newspaperTest(new NewAge());
    }

    private static void newspaperTest(Newspaper newspaper) {
        List<Headline>headlines=newspaper.getAllSportsHeadLines();

        System.out.println(newspaper.getSportsNews(headlines.get(0)));
        System.out.println(headlines.get(0).getHeading());
    }


}
```

NewAge.java

```
package com.emon.newsportal;



import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class NewAge extends Newspaper{

    protected List<Headline> getHeadlines(String baseUrl) {
        List<Headline> headlines = new ArrayList<Headline>();

        Document document = connectToTheWebpage(baseUrl);

        Elements elements = document.select("h2 a");


        for (Element element : elements) {

            Headline headline = new Headline(element.text(),
                    element.attr("href"));
            headlines.add(headline);

        }
//      System.out.println(""+headlines);
        return headlines;
    }

    protected String getNews(Headline headline) {
        Document document = connectToTheWebpage(headline.getUrl());

        return document.select("body p").get(0).text();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Headline> getAllSportsHeadLines() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getHeadlines("http://newagebd.net/category/sport/");
    }



    @Override
    public List<Headline> getALLPoliticalHeadlines() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getHeadlines("http://newagebd.net/category/politics/");
    }



    @Override
    public List<Headline> getALLEntertainmentHeadlines() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getHeadlines("http://newagebd.net/category/entertain/");
    }


    @Override
    public List<Headline> getALLBusinessHeadlines() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getHeadlines("http://newagebd.net/category/bizn/");
    }

}
```

But when I try to implement this same project in Android this gives a Nullpointer exception in the NewAge.java class

```
Elements elements = document.select("h2 a");
```

here is my error log

```
03-18 14:49:53.974    1056-1070/com.songkeet.news_a W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 14:49:53.974    1056-1070/com.songkeet.news_a W/System.err﹕ at com.songkeet.news_a.NewAge.getHeadlines(NewAge.java:27)
03-18 14:49:53.974    1056-1070/com.songkeet.news_a W/System.err﹕ at com.songkeet.news_a.NewAge.getAllSportsHeadLines(NewAge.java:50)
03-18 14:49:53.974    1056-1070/com.songkeet.news_a W/System.err﹕ at com.songkeet.news_a.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:36)
03-18 14:49:53.984    1056-1070/com.songkeet.news_a W/System.err﹕ at     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Can you suggest me I can I fix this error?
Thank you

Comment: People should leave a comment as to why they downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `NullPointerException` on

```
Elements elements = document.select("h2 a");
```

It means the `document` is null. You have to look at the `connectToTheWebpage(baseUrl)` method (you don't provide).

Comment: Here is my method protected Document connectToTheWebpage(String baseUrl) {

  Document document = null;
  try {
               document = Jsoup.connect(baseUrl).timeout(10 * 10000).get();


  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return document;
 }

Comment: I was also thinking it could be that `document.select("h2 a");` don't return what you expect since the content/layout for a mobile device is certainly different from the PC content. But then, `select` should return an empty `Elements` and not a `null`. Another possibility is you did not set the access rights for the andoid app to connect to internet: in `AndroidManifest.xml` you need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did set the access rights.